# tensor cannot be accessed , present in another function or code block

Tags: python, tensorflow, tf.keras

i am implementing post processing code for yolov3 in tensorflow using tf.keras. This code block is used to compute the mAP metrics during validation after each epoch. But while i am able to run the post processing code standalone with random data , i am getting an error while i am calling this function inside the mAP metrics code which is called via model.fit function.
the code look like this:

```
...
...
for i in tf.range(num_images):
        final_boxes , final_probs , final_class = filter_predictions(adjusted_bbox_delta[i] , det_probs[i] , det_class[i] , num_classes)
        keep_index = [index for index in range(len(final_probs)) if final_probs[index] > filter_threshold]
        final_boxes = tf.reshape([final_boxes[index] for index in keep_index] , (len(keep_index) , 4))
        final_probs = tf.reshape([final_probs[index] for index in keep_index] , (len(keep_index) , 1))
        final_class = tf.reshape([final_class[index] for index in keep_index] , (len(keep_index) , 1))
        # generate the eval bounding boxes (used to calculate metrics.)
        pred_box_objects.append(gen_box_objects(final_boxes, final_probs , final_class))
```

this is where i am calling the filter_predictions function ,

```
adjusted_box_delta.shape = [batch_size , 10647 , 4]
det_probs.shape = [batch_size , 1067 , 1]
det_class.shape = [batch_size , 1067 , 1]
```

below is the code where i am facing the problem :

```
def filter_predictions(localizations , det_probs_this_inst , det_class_this_inst , num_classes):
    # det_probs_this_inst.shape : 10647 , localizations.shape : (10647 , 4)
    max_prediction = 100
    if max_prediction < len(det_probs_this_inst):
        pred_order = tf.argsort(det_probs_this_inst)[ : -max_prediction-1:-1]
        locs = tf.gather(localizations , pred_order , axis = 0)
        probs = tf.gather(det_probs_this_inst , pred_order)
        cls_idx = tf.gather(det_class_this_inst , pred_order)

        final_boxes = []
        final_probs = []
        final_class = []
        for c in range(num_classes):
            index_per_class = tf.where(cls_idx == c)
            keep = nms(tf.squeeze(tf.gather(locs , index_per_class , axis = 0)) , tf.squeeze(tf.gather(probs , index_per_class)))
            for i in range(tf.shape(keep)[0]):
                if tf.cast(keep[i] , tf.bool):
                    final_boxes.append(locs[index_per_class[i]])
                    final_probs.append(probs[index_per_class[i]])
                    final_class.append(c)

        return [final_boxes , final_probs , final_class]
```

the error i am getting :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "train.py", line 142, in <module>
    main()
  File "train.py", line 120, in main
    train(input_size,
  File "train.py", line 81, in train
    face_detector.fit(train_data_generator ,
  File "/home/yogeesh/yogeesh/tf2/lib/python3.8/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1215, in fit
    val_logs = self.evaluate(
  File "/home/yogeesh/yogeesh/tf2/lib/python3.8/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1501, in evaluate
    tmp_logs = self.test_function(iterator)
  File "/home/yogeesh/yogeesh/tf2/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/def_function.py", line 885, in __call__
    result = self._call(*args, **kwds)
  File "/home/yogeesh/yogeesh/tf2/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/def_function.py", line 933, in _call
    self._initialize(args, kwds, add_initializers_to=initializers)
  File "/home/yogeesh/yogeesh/tf2/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/def_function.py", line 759, in _initialize
    self._stateful_fn._get_concrete_function_internal_garbage_collected(  # pylint: disable=protected-access
  File "/home/yogeesh/yogeesh/tf2/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/function.py", line 3066, in _get_concrete_function_internal_garbage_collected
    graph_function, _ = self._maybe_define_function(args, kwargs)
  File "/home/yogeesh/yogeesh/tf2/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/function.py", line 3463, in _maybe_define_function
    graph_function = self._create_graph_function(args, kwargs)
  File "/home/yogeesh/yogeesh/tf2/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/function.py", line 3298, in _create_graph_function
    func_graph_module.func_graph_from_py_func(
  File "/home/yogeesh/yogeesh/tf2/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/func_graph.py", line 1007, in func_graph_from_py_func
    func_outputs = python_func(*func_args, **func_kwargs)
  File "/home/yogeesh/yogeesh/tf2/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/def_function.py", line 668, in wrapped_fn
    out = weak_wrapped_fn().__wrapped__(*args, **kwds)
  File "/home/yogeesh/yogeesh/tf2/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/func_graph.py", line 994, in wrapper
    raise e.ag_error_metadata.to_exception(e)
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InaccessibleTensorError: in user code:

    /home/yogeesh/yogeesh/tf2/lib/python3.8/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py:1330 test_function  *
        return step_function(self, iterator)
    /home/yogeesh/yogeesh/object_detection/Yolov3_tf2/metrics/mAP.py:102 update_state  *
        box_objects = tf_postprocessing.post_process(predictions ,
    /home/yogeesh/yogeesh/object_detection/Yolov3_tf2/postprocessing/tf_postprocessing.py:148 post_process  *
        final_boxes , final_probs , final_class = filter_predictions(adjusted_bbox_delta[i] , det_probs[i] , det_class[i] , num_classes)
    /home/yogeesh/yogeesh/object_detection/Yolov3_tf2/postprocessing/tf_postprocessing.py:57 filter_predictions  *
        if max_prediction < len(det_probs_this_inst):
    /home/yogeesh/yogeesh/tf2/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/autograph/operators/control_flow.py:1172 if_stmt
        _tf_if_stmt(cond, body, orelse, get_state, set_state, symbol_names, nouts)
    /home/yogeesh/yogeesh/tf2/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/autograph/operators/control_flow.py:1218 _tf_if_stmt
        final_cond_vars = control_flow_ops.cond(
    /home/yogeesh/yogeesh/tf2/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/util/dispatch.py:206 wrapper
        return target(*args, **kwargs)
    /home/yogeesh/yogeesh/tf2/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/util/deprecation.py:549 new_func
        return func(*args, **kwargs)
    /home/yogeesh/yogeesh/tf2/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/control_flow_ops.py:1254 cond
        return cond_v2.cond_v2(pred, true_fn, false_fn, name)
    /home/yogeesh/yogeesh/tf2/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/cond_v2.py:82 cond_v2
        true_graph = func_graph_module.func_graph_from_py_func(
    /home/yogeesh/yogeesh/tf2/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/func_graph.py:1011 func_graph_from_py_func
        func_outputs = nest.map_structure(convert, func_outputs,
    /home/yogeesh/yogeesh/tf2/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/util/nest.py:869 map_structure
        structure[0], [func(*x) for x in entries],
    /home/yogeesh/yogeesh/tf2/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/util/nest.py:869 <listcomp>
        structure[0], [func(*x) for x in entries],
    /home/yogeesh/yogeesh/tf2/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/func_graph.py:971 convert
        x = deps_ctx.mark_as_return(x)
    /home/yogeesh/yogeesh/tf2/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/auto_control_deps.py:231 mark_as_return
        tensor = array_ops.identity(tensor)
    /home/yogeesh/yogeesh/tf2/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/util/dispatch.py:206 wrapper
        return target(*args, **kwargs)
    /home/yogeesh/yogeesh/tf2/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/array_ops.py:289 identity
        ret = gen_array_ops.identity(input, name=name)
    /home/yogeesh/yogeesh/tf2/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gen_array_ops.py:3945 identity
        _, _, _op, _outputs = _op_def_library._apply_op_helper(
    /home/yogeesh/yogeesh/tf2/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/op_def_library.py:748 _apply_op_helper
        op = g._create_op_internal(op_type_name, inputs, dtypes=None,
    /home/yogeesh/yogeesh/tf2/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/func_graph.py:597 _create_op_internal
        inp = self.capture(inp)
    /home/yogeesh/yogeesh/tf2/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/func_graph.py:642 capture
        raise errors.InaccessibleTensorError(

    InaccessibleTensorError: The tensor 'Tensor("while/cond/while_1/cond/strided_slice_1/GatherV2_1:0", shape=(1, 4), dtype=float32)' cannot be accessed here: it is defined in another function or code block. Use return values, explicit Python locals or TensorFlow collections to access it. Defined in: FuncGraph(name=while_cond_while_1_cond_true_12011, id=140480887970688); accessed from: FuncGraph(name=while_cond_true_11525, id=140480887162192).
    

2021-10-22 04:37:19.739693: W tensorflow/core/kernels/data/generator_dataset_op.cc:107] Error occurred when finalizing GeneratorDataset iterator: Failed precondition: Python interpreter state is not initialized. The process may be terminated.
     [[{{node PyFunc}}]]
```

i wonder if the problem is somehow caused due to for loop that i am using for num_images.
please share some insight.

Answer (score 2):

i am posting my solution here incase if someone is also stuck under same situation.
So basically the problem is that, tensorflow under graph mode is not very compatible with python list, so for each input signature a new graph fucntion is created, hence it is not recommended to have mutable python objects like lists which might have different shape for each fucntion call to be used in the fucntion signature (parameters and their shape).
The error explains it all, as the list is getting expanded or might have a different shape the signatue is also changed and hence a new graph func is created.

Solution :
its better to use tensor objects , and one must use list like structure then recommended use is to use tf.TensorArray object.
For more details , refer to this github issue : https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/52617